# I am stuck in Do you accept the EULA you just read? (y/n)

Tags: shell, jenkins, yocto

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set your desired DISTRO and MACHINE values
export DISTRO=fsl-hidden
export MACHINE=hidden

# Create a directory for your Yocto build and navigate to it
mkdir -p hidden
cd hidden

# Initialize the repo with the specified manifest
repo init -u https://bitbucket.org/hidden/hidden.git -b branch -m hidden

# Configure Git credentials to avoid prompts during repo sync
git config --global credential.helper store
echo 'https://hidden@bitbucket.org' >> ~/.git-credentials

# Synchronize the Yocto layers
repo sync -j1 --no-repo-verify

. ./imx-setup-release.sh -b build_dir

# Build the ifupdown recipe using bitbake
bitbake ifupdown
```

When I run this command line " . ./imx-setup-release.sh -b build_dir" and it gets stuck at - Do you accept the EULA you just read? (y/n) - (I had source in the ./ part, but jenkins didn't accept it so I changed it to yes | . ./imx-setup-release.sh -b build_dir but terminal and jenkins react differently.

[Command Prompt Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymEDo.png)

If I press q, it recognizes and accepts the y I pressed.
[Command Prompt Output after press q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGUVM.png)

Jenkisde . ./imx-setup-release.sh -b it prints the license txt without asking for anything like press space or q, but it prints Do you accept the EULA you just read? (y/n) forever. yes | . ./imx-setup-release.sh and it keeps printing y on the screen until I abort.

[Jenkis output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fwzK.png)

[Jenkins output last lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE9U2.png)

My question is how can I pass this automatically and which shell command should I use?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by just adding yes | head -n 1 |